# How to get total disk space in Linux with Java?

Tags: java, linux, apache, jsp

I am able to get free disk space. How would I get the total disk space?

My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils;

public class DiskSpace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            //calculate free disk space
            double freeDiskSpace = FileSystemUtils.freeSpaceKb(args[0]);
            System.out.println(args[0]);

            //convert the number into gigabyte
            double freeDiskSpaceGB = freeDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024;

            System.out.println("Free Disk Space (GB):" + freeDiskSpaceGB);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`FileSystemUtils` do not have method for total space of disk ??? hopes for your reply

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
  System.out.println(new File("/").getTotalSpace()/1024/1024/1024); //in GB
```

Comment: Nirmal how would i get the disk space of particular drive ?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Java6 the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace%28%29) class will do:

```
public long getTotalSpace()
public long getFreeSpace()
public long getUsableSpace()
```

Comment: Thanks it help me alot i am using version 6 :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Generally we thank people by voting up or accepting their answers if they are instructive.

Comment: @ amir how would i initialize file for the total space ? as i have seen in example it is using like this File file = new File("C:"); so i am initialising it as File file = new File("/root"); and dividing it by 1024 or 1024/1024 two times to get result in gb but it is giving me 7 as output while the orignal total disk space for root folder is 1.1GB ???