# How to redirect java File to linux specific path

Tags: java, linux

I need to use with Java the API File.
I would like to redirect in a specific path of Linux,
the goal is that to measure the disk space of a particular
partition, but I get the result of root partition.
This is the code:

```
final long GIGABYTE = 1073741824;
    File file = new File("/dev/root");
    float totalSpace = file.getTotalSpace() / GIGABYTE;
```

Seems that file charge only the root path --> /
Could I redirect file in a specific path ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your use of the word "redirect". Could you explain?

Comment: is it like you want to measure the size of the file, but you get the size of root partition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get total disk space in Linux with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477390/how-to-get-total-disk-space-in-linux-with-java)

Comment: I would like to measure only a part of my disk: for instance I want calculate only the disk /dev/root but every path I insert I get always the disk of the root part /

Answer (score 0):

I solved simply inserting the jar file  in the specific path.
I wanted calculate the disk space in this path /dev/root, so 
i putt inside there the file with this path;
File file = new File("/");